# How Initialize T type c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dto

I Have a BaseController.

```
 public abstract class BaseController<TEntity, TNewDTO, TEditDTO> : Controller, ICrudController<TNewDTO, TEditDTO>
        where TEntity : class
        where TNewDTO : new()
        where TEditDTO : new()
    {
    public virtual ActionResult Edit(int? Id)
    {
        if (Id == null) return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400);
        var ent = _db.Set<TEntity>().Find(Id);
        if (ent == null) return new HttpStatusCodeResult(404);

        var editDTO = new TEditDTO();

        editDTO = ent; // how initilze?


        return View(editDTO);

    }
}
```

in Edit Action, check validation, find entity from context and fill Edit data Transfer Object (DTO)
EditDTO and ent have some properties. **how can i initialize automatically one T with another t type with properties with same name and type**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)

> AutoMapper is a simple little library built to solve a deceptively complex problem - getting rid of code that mapped one object to another. This type of code is rather dreary and boring to write, so why not invent a tool to do it for us?

Comment: Wonder why anyone would downvote this answer and then not leave a comment.